# Appharbor fails to publish asp.net mvc 4 application

Tags: msbuild, appharbor

Trying to launch my project on appharbor and it fails with this:

> "D:\temp\cijsrn4n.1kq\input\TinyBlogMvc4.sln" (default target)
>       (1) ->
>       "D:\temp\cijsrn4n.1kq\input\TinyBlogMvc4\TinyBlogMvc4.csproj" (default
>       target) (2) ->       (_CopyWebApplicationLegacy target) ->
>       C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplica
>       tions\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(178,5): **error MSB3021: Unable
>       to copy file "obj\Debug\build.force"** to "D:\temp\cijsrn4n.
>       1kq\output_PublishedWebsites\TinyBlogMvc4\obj\Debug\build.force".
>       Could not find a part of the path 'obj\Debug\build.force'.
>       [D:\temp\cijsrn4n.1kq\input\TinyBlogMvc4\TinyBlogMvc4.csproj]
>       C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplica
>       tions\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(178,5): **error MSB3021: Unable
>       to copy file
>       "obj\Debug\DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache"** to
>       "D:\temp\cijsrn4n.      1kq\output_PublishedWebsites\TinyBlogMvc4\obj
>       \Debug\DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache". Could not find
>       a part of the path
>       'obj\Debug\DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache'.
>       [D:\temp\cijsrn4n.      1kq\input\TinyBlogMvc4\TinyBlogMvc4.csproj]

```
          0 Warning(s) 2 Error(s)
```

It builds on my pc just fine, any ideas what I'm missing?

.NET Framework version is 4.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created project from scratch and then compared and found this:

> ```
> <Content Include="obj\Debug\build.force" />
> ```

How it appeared there, have no idea, but that was the reason.

Comment: For me at least, choosing "Include in Project" on the `obj` directory caused Visual Studio to add the offending lines.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I solved removed from the **.csproj** file these rows:

```
<Content Include="obj\Debug\AqAUI.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt" />
<Content Include="obj\Debug\AqAUI.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache" />
<Content Include="obj\Debug\build.force" />
<Content Include="obj\Debug\DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `_CopyWebApplicationLegacy` target in your project file is causing problems. If you don't need it, consider removing it. Alternatively, you should fix the path issue. It looks like an invalid path is generated: `output_PublishedWebsites` should probably be `output\_PublishedWebsites`. There are suggestions on how to debug stuff like this in the [FAQ](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions/)

Comment: I've found in FAQ what build command line appharbor is using and that helped me recreate issue on my dev pc. Thing is, that I can't find any direct reference to _CopyWebApplicationLegacy target. If I'm trying to build from command line empty MVC project, it builds ok, I've compared project files and could not find anything suspicious.