# Azure Publish Error - Could not copy the file obj\Debug\build.force

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-sdk-.net

I tried to publish my Azure Cloud project, and I am getting the following error message

> Could not copy the file  `obj\Debug\build.force` because it was not found
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets

I am getting this error when I tried to publish by right clicking on the cloud project, selecting build configuration `Debug`, and then clicking `publish`.

If I select  build configuration `Release` it published successfully.

Looks like this is happening intermittently .

Even when I select Release mode, I am getting the above same error:

- Right-click `Cloudproject`
- Select `Publish`
- Select Environment `Staging`
- Select Build Configuration `Release`

**UPDATE**
Whenever I got this error ,I tried with different combinations between Staging / Production/ Release during publish and sometimes it works.

Any ideas as to what could be going wrong?

I am using Windows 10, VS2015 and the Azure SDK 2.8

Comment: Possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953741/appharbor-fails-to-publish-asp-net-mvc-4-application  Suspect he removed the `<Content Include="..." />` tag from the project, as it seems that this file doesn't always exist so you probably don't want it.

Comment: Which file do I need to include the above tag.? I saw the answer on the link you mentioned .But I am not clear where to add that tag .Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets  ? or application .proj file ? or Cloud.proj file ?

Comment: If it is to be added within the cloud proj file then which setting or tag should I include ?

Comment: Either your `application.proj` or the `Cloud.proj` - should be pretty each to open each of them and search for `build.force`.

Comment: I tried adding <Content Include="..." /> to the .proj  ,but no luck

Comment: I think you need to **remove** that tag, if it exists, for the `build.force` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get this error too often. I solve this error the following way.

1. Open notepad++ in admin mode.
2. Open the `.csproj` file of my project in notepad++.
3. Remove the following line from `.csproj` file.

   `"Content Include=obj\\Debug\\build.force"`
4. Save `.csproj` file.
5. Reload the project in visual studio.
6. Publish the project.

This solution works for me. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted Bin debug and release folders and files inside. Re-build and publish to azure worked just fine